# How does /proc/apm work?

Tags: android, power-management, battery, proc

I'm currently trying to develop an app that determines battery statistics on Android devices.  I want to access /proc/apm to see what is inside but on my test device I cannot find it.  My device does not actually have a battery, it is just a board given to me that runs on power from the wall.  Is that why it doesn't appear to exist?  Is the file created only when there is a battery?

Thank you!